# What's the etag in IoT Hub device twins for?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I'm developing a web application in .NET Core 3 and I'm using the Microsoft.Azure.Devices.RegistryManager to access an Azure Iot hub.

When I call registryManager.UpdateTwinAsync(), I have to send in the "etag". And sometimes the etag changes and I get errors stating that there is an etag mismatch.

I basically don't understand what the etag's purpose is and how I can update device twins in a safe manner. Anyone?

I tried catching those exceptions and fetching the etag from the device twin and retrying up to 15 times in a row with 2 seconds wait in between and that helps, but this error pops up every now and then. I would think that applying the device id would be enough to update a device twin but apparently not

Please help!

Answer (score 7):

So in a simple terms we can say that **ETag - Entity tag** will keep changing when ever we see there is a change in device status or any other updates.

> *A string representing a weak ETag for the device identity, as per [RFC7232 Section 2.3 Etag](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.3).*

> *An **entity-tag** is an opaque validator for
> differentiating between multiple representations of the same
> resource, regardless of whether those multiple representations are
> due to resource state changes over time*

**For example:** Enable and Disable an IoT Device and check the 'Get device Info' from  Visual Studio Code ([Azure IoT Hub Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.azure-iot-toolkit))

**Step 1)** I have an initial IoT device with status Enabled and I can see an Etag value.

**Step 2)** When I disabled the device on IoT Hub portal, and then did second query 'Get Device Info' call, I see a different value on ETag.

[image]

**Step 3)** Now when I queried for the second time (like after 5 mins interval), I see the **Etag value remains same** for the same disabled state of device.

[image]

**For more info please visit [Device identity properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-identity-registry#device-identity-properties), [Module identity properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-identity-registry#module-identity-properties)

**Please let us know if you need more help on this!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the ETag is used to ensure consistency on the device twin when you're updating it. It's read-only so you would get it from your device twin and pass it back to `UpdateTwinAsync()` with your changes. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins#optimistic-concurrency)

I'm not sure what you mean when you say the ETag is changing - can you provide some code of what you are doing (or clarify when the ETag is changing)?

I created a video on YouTube that demos how to read/write Azure Device Twins, so feel free to check it out, hopefully it helps you! [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrhhQhqf2fE)

Comment: Thanks. What I mean is that I've experienced the etag for a particular device changing every now and then and I'm not sure what causes it. In other words, for the lifetime of a single device, the etag doesn't seem to have the same value always.

Answer (score 0):

For some additional information about how device twins use optimistic concurrency to ensure consistency when there are potentially multiple updates from different users, see [Understand and use device twins in IoT Hub > Optimistic concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins#optimistic-concurrency) on Microsoft Docs.